# What are the best practices to initialize a Next.js webapp with data from an API and adding it to the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, redux, next.js

I'm using Zustand for state management (although I'd imagine the same principle applies to all state management libraries such as Redux or Recoil). I've thought about and tried:

1. Fetching data using `getStaticProps()` and using `useEffect()` to push the data to state during the first page render. The problem is that the data isn't pushed to state until that specific page is loaded. I don't want to use `getInitialProps()`, as it's being deprecated.
2. A solution that worked (sort of, not sure it's best practice though) was using SWR on **_app.js** to fetch the API data when the app first initializes, and pushing the data to state with `useEffect()`. This way I could freely populate the pages by using the data from state, and it only required one API call. Example below:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  
  // Load data from api with SWR
  const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    "https://example.com/api",
    fetcher
  );

  // Get data setter from state
  const setData = useStore((state) => state.setData);

  // When data is fetched successfully, populate state with data
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setData(data);
    }
  }, [data]);

  if (error) return "Error has occured";
  if (!data) return "Loading...";

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Are there better ways to fetch data and use it to populate state on the first time the app is loaded? What are the best practices?

Comment: you don't need to use any store or state management when u use SWR. swr itself has mutate() for you to manipulate the state

Answer (score 4):

I got it working the right way using Zustand context provider and initializing it using Nextjs `pageProps` and `getStaticProps()`.

**_app.js**

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const createStore = initStore(pageProps.initZustand);
  return (
    <Provider createStore={createStore}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

**store.js**

```
export const { Provider, useStore } = createContext();

let store = {
  names: ["Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3"],
  random: [],
  setRandom: (data) => {
    set((state) => ({ random: data }));
  },
};

export const initStore = (data) => {
  const createStore = () =>
    create(
      devtools((set, get) => ({
        ...store,
        ...data,
      }))
    );

  return createStore;
};
```

**index.js getStaticProps:**

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      initZustand: {
        posts: posts,
      },
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was how I solved it to allow a Zustand store + persist to hydrate from both localStorage AND/OR pageProps globally.

This is also easily portable over to NextJS 13 server components when they are production ready.

User store logs in, gets a cookie set by the backend, and then fetches a user.  The user is persisted in zustand/persist but can also be returned from the server unwrapping the cookie in pageProps.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useUser } from 'stores/user'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // some pages hydrate from the server
  const { user } = pageProps
  if (user) {
    useUser.setState({ user: user })
  }
  // some from local storage to avoid getServerSideProps
  const hyrdratedUser = useUser(state => state.user)
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoaded(true)
  }, [hyrdratedUser])

  return loaded ? <Component {...pageProps} /> : null
}
```